# How can I simulate a peer-to-peer communications channel using PHP, MySQL DB and JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

The challenge I'm facing is simulating a communication channel between two users of a website (e.g. gaming site), by using solely the technologies mentioned in the title.

Recently I've developed an online chess website where, the idea behind which was to give users the chance to play "live" matches too, not just lengthy games where you would make a move, then come back in 1-15 days to see if your opponent has responded. And the way this game engine works implies sending asynchronous requests to the server, both to update the info related to the game (in case you make a move), but also to verify if anything has changed (if you are waiting for the opponent to move).

To better explain this... the player whose turn it is (the browser of course) sends an async. request to update the game info, exactly when he makes his move. Meanwhile, the opponent sends PERIODIC requests, "asking" if anything has changed. If anything does change, the roles switch after the board updates.

Timers are behind the functionality of the engine, so my question to you is this: How would you go about simulating a com channel between two players, while trying not to put too much stress on the server, but also having games update as fast as possible, in order to maintain the "live" feeling to it. This is most important in 1 minute games (one of the available categories). Because in that case, requests NEED to take place VERY often (at least 1 second). But server responses could delay, there would be much stress on the server when having hundreds of games available at the same time etc... so you see my problem.

I look forward to hearing from you guys and picking your brain if you have any good ideas :)

Cheers!
Andrei

PS: In case you want to try it, the name is [**e-chess960.com**](http://e-chess960.com)

Comment: Check out node.js and socket.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would want to builds a socket server. node.js would be a good javascript based library to use for a socket server. each client would create a socket connection to the socket server, then when a client sends a message to the socket server, the socket server could immediately send the message back out to its subscribers without having to store it anywhere.

socket servers require socket access, which usually requires a vps instead of a shared server.

to make the solution work, you would require that the clients have the ability to create socket connections to your server. some browsers already can as part of html5, but not all yet. you could also use Flash as a way to create a socket connection.

Comment: +1 for node.js. Use socket.io in combo with node.js to achieve crossbrowser compatibility for full-duplex communication. This is piece of cake to do with the two mentioned libraries.

Comment: Well, I have to admit that from what I've read, this is some pretty awesome technology. I've come across Node in the past but didn't realize what it was, so I turned my head away. Until now...I believe it's exactly the kind of technology I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

What you actually want is not pulling the server every second, but instead keep a connection open and use the [observer-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to distribute updates to the specific clients (in other words: push instead of pull). That way, your server resources will not get swamped by a new connection for every second and every client. A library to accomplish that is the Comet Library. Check out this nice [tutorial](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start) for a sample application.

Comment: I didn't downgrade anyone's vote. Or was the question not aimed at me?

Comment: it wasn't pointed at you, but at the persons that downgraded without explaining why (that's a rude behaviour IMO). Did you check out the tutorial and the Comet Library?

Comment: I noticed that I don't even have the possibility to vote yet. Not enough 'reputation' :)) Anyway, I went through the tutorial you linked to, but it doesn't seem to be what I need. Because there can be hundreds of games at the same time, different games of course, which have completely different information associated. And from what I read in the tutorial, comet is used to broadcast thee same data to all connected clients... But I don't see the relation to my problem, sorry. Please explain.

Comment: @nadrei-oniga: You do not send all data to all clients, but only to those interested in one observed subject. Assuming you have a game A played by four clients 1,2,3,4 and a game B played by 3,4,5,6, then 1-4 would declare to observe A and 3-6 would declare to observe B. Consequently, 1 and 2 would only get updates from Game A, 3 and 4 would get updates from both games and 5 and 6 would get updates only from game B. So in a nutshell, you share the data only between the observers of one subject - if you have several games, you have several subjects. I hope that cleared it up.

Comment: The example "schematic" I already understood. But that wasn't the actual issue. Right now, from what I can tell, the server is supposed to constantly retrieve information about all the games active on the website (there can be thousands!) and broadcast that information to all clients connected. Even with each client being set to "listen in" on a particular game (the one that the user is looking at), how does this solve the problem of stress on the server?

Comment: The filter is not in the client, but in the server. So the server only sends out the information on one subject (or one game) to the clients who observe the specific subject (are playing one specific game). It reduces the stress on the server, as the clients won't connect to the server all the time and ask if there's something new. Instead, a connection is held open all the time and the server will send the updates when they are available. it's basically the same as dqhendricks solution, but with a framework and without the hassle of having to implement the pattern itself.

Comment: @Andrej-Oniga oh, and btw: you should pick one answer as solution. If you have a low answer rate, less users will try to answer your question. ;)